# how to create database in codeigniter with another hostname?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have 2 servers, one for files and another for database.

I'm trying to create another database but i get an error of "Access denied for user username@files_server", but the main database is on data_server.

my code is:

```
// create database
$this->load->dbforge();

$this->dbforge->create_database("new_database");
```

Comment: The error you get is from failing to open a connection, which has nothing to do with the code you've shown.

Comment: it's because i don't have database on this server. i'm trying to make a new database on the other server

Comment: But you still have to connect to the server (and this is where the error occurs) before you can create a new database.

Answer (score -1):

One of the most common things I've found is that the username was generated with the incorrect domain name.  For instance, I've noticed that in some environments, you will be denied from localhost if you have username@%.  You may be able to dig through the DB logs and figure out what domain your system is broadcasting with and make sure that the user created in the DB matches the username@your.computers.domain exactly.

Mike Miller

CTO PVBid

[www.pvbid.com](http://www.pvbid.com)